# Serialize hash as string similar to json with single quotes in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

Is there a way to convert a hash, possibly nested:

```
{:event=>"subscribe", :channel=>"data_channel", :parameters=>{:api_key=>"XXX", :sign=>"YYY"}}
```

into a string in specified format as below?

```
"{'event':'subscribe', 'channel':'data_channel', 'parameters': {'api_key':'XXX', 'sign':'YYY'}}"
```

**EDIT**

The format reminds JSON, but practically is not due to single quotes.

Comment: "Is there a way" - Yes, it's called "serialization". Usually a google query like "ruby hash to <specified format>" helps me.

Comment: What is `ws_client.send str`? Is that relevant to your question? Please don't write irrelevant things. If you were trying to imply that the string should be in JSON format, then write that explicitly, not in an implicit way.

Comment: @sawa That's to stress that WS server accepts specified format only. It rejects any other formats, including strings with double quotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make JSON, then fix it up:

```
require 'json'

hash = {:event=>"subscribe", :channel=>"data_channel",
        :parameters=>{:api_key=>"XXX", :sign=>%q{Miles "Chief" O'Brien}}}

puts hash.to_json.gsub(/"((?:\\[\"]|[^\"])*)"/) { |x|
  %Q{'#{$1.gsub(/'|\\"/, ?' => %q{\'}, %q{\\"} => ?")}'}
}
# => {'event':'subscribe','channel':'data_channel',
#    'parameters':{'api_key':'XXX','sign':'Miles "Chief" O\'Brien'}}
```

EDIT: The first regex says: match a double quote, then a sequence of either escaped double quotes/backslashes, or non-double-quote/backslash characters, then a double quote again. This makes sure we only find strings, and not accidental half-strings like `"Miles \"`. For each such string, we surround the bit that was inside the double quotes (`$1`) with single quotes, and run a sub-replacement on it that will find escaped double quotes and unescaped single quotes, unescape the former and escape the latter.

Also, sorry about wonky highlighting, seems StackOverflow syntax highlighter can't deal with alternate forms of Ruby quoting, but they're so convenient when you're working with quote characters...

Answer (score 3):

Your desired output looks like a JSON. Try

```
require 'json'

JSON.dump(hash)
=> "{\"event\":\"subscribe\",\"channel\":\"data_channel\",\"parameters\":{\"api_key\":\"XXX\",\"sign\":\"YYY\"}}"
```

Comment: That looks good, but I need single quoted string. As you mentioned just replacing quotes is not very good idea

Comment: I looked into JSON.generate, but couldn't find option for quotes

Comment: Because single quotes is not an option for JSON. JSON specification requires double quotes

Comment: If you really need single quotes then JSON is not what you're looking for

Comment: Yes, it's a very strange format, like YAML wrapped into brackets, but that's what I have to deal with as websocket client

Answer (score 2):

To have single quotes you can try something like:

```
JSON.dump(hash).gsub('"', '\'')
```

It returns:

```
{'event':'subscribe','channel':'data_channel','parameters':{'api_key':'XXX','sign':'YYY'}}
```

Comment: If a string contains a double quote, you replace it with a single quote. It does not seem a good idea.

Comment: @Ursus: And it'd make invalid json anyway.

Comment: Yes, but the question was not about generating JSONs? it was about converting a hash to a single quoted json-like string. The OP can decide on his own wether it makes sense to use this logic (based on type of data he is handling) or not. I up voted the first comment because it makes sense to highlight and mention such a side effect / potential bug.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev that too but the user never said JSON so I'm not 100% sure yet :D

Comment: @Ursus: that's true, they didn't. I am still 98% sure it's json, though :)

Comment: Yes, I need single-quoted string

Comment: Since I couldn't find robust solution, I ended up using this method temporarly